# Configuring Script Handlers Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.5

I am trying to make a simple application using Google App Engine.

Below is my code

`helloworld.py`

```
print "hello"

class helloworld():
        def myfunc(self):
                st = "inside class"
                return st
```

`test.py`

```
import helloworld

hw_object  = helloworld.helloworld()
print  hw_object.myfunc()
```

`app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py

- url: /.*
  script: test.py
```

When I run my application via `http://localhost:10000` it prints only `hello` whereas my expected output is `hello` and `inside class`.

My directory structure

```
E:\helloworld>dir
app.yaml       helloworld.py  test.py
```

I am pretty sure this has something to do with [Script Handlers](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Script_Handlers).So, what is the correct way to define handlers and what is wrong in my way of defining them.

Comment: Do you mean to have two identical route regexps?

Comment: I mean how can i configure my `app.yaml` if there are multiple scripts in my folder.I tried the above pattern it didn't worked.What i need is if i run `localhost:10000` both my scripts should be executed but this is not happening.

Comment: @AdamBernier: I tried `url: /test/.*` but still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your first handler pattern `/.*` matches `http://localhost:10000`, the remaining handlers are all ignored.

You can updated your `app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /hello
  script: helloworld.py

- url: /test
  script: test.py
```

And browse `http://localhost:10000/test`

Answer (score 0):

Please walk through the Getting Started guide from the appengine documentation. It will help you get through the initial setup problems like this.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/helloworld.html

Here is the sample Handler from that documentation.

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                 [('/', MainPage)],
                                 debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that the class extends webapp.RequestHandler, the method name is get (or post if you are responding to a http post request) Also the extra code at the bottom for setting up the application. You can add extra URL's to the application by adding arguments to the WSGIApplication. For example:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                 [('/', MainPage)],
                                 [('/help/', HelpPage)],
                                 debug=True)
```

Also note that in your app.yaml as both scripts refer to the same url pattern, there is no way that any request will ever get to test.py. The normal pattern is to have specific url patterns at the top and a catch-all patter last.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem too. Expanding on Hamish's answer, and correcting the last part where the square brackets are:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
                            ('/', MainPage), 
                            ('/help/', HelpPage)],
                            debug=True)
```

Reference:
https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html

** Edit I also had an extra closing bracket in my code above. Changed that now.